# unable to access variables in extended view page in symfony

Tags: symfony, variables

I'm passing values to a view page called abc.html.php using render in Symfony. Now this view page extends a header. The variable i'm passing from controller is not accessible in the extended view. Is there any way to do so ?
In symfony, the variables i pass from controller and not accessible in the view pages which are extended. In that case, i want to declare a global variable in config/packages/twig.php.

How can i define a global variable with session data ?
or is there any way to use variables of controller in extended view page ?

I tried accessing it. But it doesn't work out.

In my controller

```
return $this->render('abc.html.php',[
   'variable'  =>  'some array or string',
]);
```

Now i'm unable to use the 'variable' in a base file which is extended in abc.html.php like this:

```
<?php echo $this->render('includes/base.html.php');?>
```

Comment: Could you please share your code ? (Controller and corresponding twig files) ? There is no way to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use render controller instead of extends or include template. you should create a function inside your controller witch render the header view then you call this function with render controller.
Now you can pass any variable to your header view from the controller.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: But in few cases i'm not using twigs. I'm using .php files. What's in that case ?